# Only update 100 values simultaneously one api call via Ansible

Tags: api, ansible, vapix

I've got a .yml file filled with hundreds of configuration values for an Axis network camera. The contents look like this:

```
---
axis:
  config:
    "Bandwidth.Limit": 0
    "HTTPS.AllowTLS1": "no"
    "HTTPS.AllowTLS11": "no"
    "HTTPS.AllowSSLV3": "no"
    "HTTPS.Ciphers": AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA
    "HTTPS.Enabled": "yes"
    "HTTPS.Port": 443
    ...
```

The Axis API, called Vapix, provides an update function that updates a value, so I circled through the values and triggered a new API call with every iteration:

```
---
  - name: update parameters
    local_action:
      module: uri 
      user: "{{ axis_snmp_role.login_user }}"
      password: "{{ axis_snmp_role.login_password }}"
      url: "{{ axis_snmp_role.server_url }}?action=update&{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}"
      validate_certs: false
    with_dict: "{{ axis.config }}"
```

Turns out this works, but takes forever. I manually found out that it's possible to update multiple values with one API call by glueing the key/value-pairs together with the &-symbol like this:

```
https://{{ axis_snmp_role.server_url }}/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=update&ImageSource.I0.Sensor.ExposureValue=100&Image.I0.Appearance.Compression=50
```

So I used this to buid one big API call that will set all the values at once.

```
---
  - name: Create parameter list
    set_fact:
      my_parameters: "{{ my_parameters | default([]) + [item.key + '=' + item.value|string|urlencode() ] }}"
    with_dict: "{{ axis.config }}"

  - name: update parameters
    #no_log: true
    local_action:
      module: uri 
      user: "{{ axis_snmp_role.login_user }}"
      password: "{{ axis_snmp_role.login_password }}"
      url: "{{ axis_snmp_role.server_url }}?action=update&{{ my_parameters | join('&') }}"
      validate_certs: false
    #with_dict: "{{ axis.config }}"
```

Turns out the network camera doesn't like to get so many values at once, so I guess I am stuck with having to split the process up a bit.

Is it possible to craft an Ansible loop that reads 100 key/values-pairs at once, creates one big api call with all of them, sends it off and repeats this until the end of the config file is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Is it possible to craft an Ansible loop that reads 100 key/values-pairs at once, creates one big API call with all of them, sends it off and repeats this until the end of the config file is reached?"*

A: Yes. It's possible. Below is a procedure on how to split the parameters. Set the variable `period` to 100 and test it.

Given `axis.config` declare the `period` for testing

```
  vars:
    axis:
      config:
        "Bandwidth.Limit": 0
        "HTTPS.AllowTLS1": "no"
        "HTTPS.AllowTLS11": "no"
        "HTTPS.AllowSSLV3": "no"
        "HTTPS.Ciphers": AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA
        "HTTPS.Enabled": "yes"
        "HTTPS.Port": 443
    period: 2
```

Create a list of parameters and calculate the length of the list

```
    - set_fact:
        config_list: "{{ config_list|default([]) + [item.key ~ '=' ~ item.value] }}"
      loop: "{{ axis.config|dict2items }}"
    - debug:
        var: config_list
    - set_fact:
        config_length: "{{ config_list|length }}"
    - debug:
        var: config_length
```

give

```
    "config_list": [
        "HTTPS.Ciphers=AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA", 
        "HTTPS.AllowTLS11=no", 
        "HTTPS.AllowTLS1=no", 
        "HTTPS.Enabled=yes", 
        "HTTPS.Port=443", 
        "Bandwidth.Limit=0", 
        "HTTPS.AllowSSLV3=no"
    ]


    "config_length": "7"
```

Split `config_list` to sublists of the length `period`

```
    - set_fact:
        split_list: "{{ split_list|default([]) +
                        [config_list[split0|int:split1|int]] }}"
      vars:
        split0: "{{ ansible_loop.previtem|default(0) }}"
        split1: "{{ ansible_loop.last|ternary(config_length, item) }}"
      loop: "{{ range(period, config_length|int, period)|list }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: yes
    - debug:
        var: split_list
```

gives

```
    "split_list": [
        [
            "HTTPS.Ciphers=AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA", 
            "HTTPS.AllowTLS11=no"
        ], 
        [
            "HTTPS.AllowTLS1=no", 
            "HTTPS.Enabled=yes"
        ], 
        [
            "HTTPS.Port=443", 
            "Bandwidth.Limit=0", 
            "HTTPS.AllowSSLV3=no"
        ]
    ]
```

Loop the list and join the parameters

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|join('&') }}"
      loop: "{{ split_list }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": "HTTPS.Ciphers=AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA&HTTPS.AllowTLS11=no"
    "msg": "HTTPS.AllowTLS1=no&HTTPS.Enabled=yes"
    "msg": "HTTPS.Port=443&Bandwidth.Limit=0&HTTPS.AllowSSLV3=no"
```

---

With some custom filters (below) the procedure will be simplified

```
$ cat filter_plugins/dict_filters.py
def dict2list(d):
    l = []
    for i in d:
        h = {i:d[i]}
        l.append(h)
    return l

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'dict2list' : dict2list
            }

$ cat filter_plugins/list_filters.py
def list_split(l, p):
    split_list = []
    for i in range(p, len(l)+p, p):
        if i == p:
            split_list.append(l[0:p])
        elif i > len(l):
            split_list.append(l[j:])
        else:
            split_list.append(l[j:i])
        j = i
    return split_list

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'list_split' : list_split
            }

$ cat filter_plugins/hash_filters.py
def hash_to_tuple(h):
    return h.items()[0]

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'hash_to_tuple': hash_to_tuple
            }
```

The tasks below

```
    - set_fact:
        config_list: "{{ axis.config|
                         dict2list|
                         map('hash_to_tuple')|
                         map('join', '=')|
                         list }}"

    - set_fact:
        split_list: "{{ config_list|list_split(period) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|join('&') }}"
      loop: "{{ split_list }}"
```

give the same result

```
    "msg": "HTTPS.Ciphers=AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA&HTTPS.AllowTLS11=no"
    "msg": "HTTPS.AllowTLS1=no&HTTPS.Enabled=yes"
    "msg": "HTTPS.Port=443&Bandwidth.Limit=0"
    "msg": "HTTPS.AllowSSLV3=no"
```